# How to pass a model to a base.html that all templates extend from base.html

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a Django project which I have a base.html that all templates inheritance from that. Then I include a category.html file in base.html which is just my navigation bar. So I have a model named Category and I want to pass this model to category.html to show my categories. I don't know how to do that?

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}


<html lang="en" style="height: 100%;">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    {% comment %} <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS --> {% endcomment %}
    <link href="{% static 'fontawesome/css/all.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"> <!--load all styles -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/mdb.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/style.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Mega menu style -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bs4megamenu.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block extra_head %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block slideshow %}
    {% endblock slideshow %}

</head>

<body>

<!-- Category Navbar -->
{% include 'category_navbar.html' %}
<!-- Category Navbar -->

<!-- Body Content -->
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
<!-- Body Content -->



<!-- Footer and scripts-->
{% include 'footer.html' %}
{% include 'scripts.html' %}
<!-- Footer and scripts-->
</body>
</html>
```

model.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="general")
    category_description = models.TextField()
    category_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="categories/images/", blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True ,related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)    #enforcing that there can not be two
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    def __str__(self):
        full_path = [self.category_name]
        k = self.parent                          

        while k is not None:
            full_path.append(k.category_name)
            k = k.parent

        return ' -> '.join(full_path[::-1])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.category_name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Use a custom template tag or a context processor.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Roseman commented, create a custom template tag or context processor.

When creating a custom Template Tag there are two approaches:

1. create a template tag that adds a context variable and use it in `category_navbar.html`.
2. create an inclusion tag and use it to instead of `{% include 'category_navbar.html' %}`

Here is how the second approach looks like:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('category_navbar.html', takes_context=True)
def category_navbar(parent_context):
    context = {"categories": Category.objects.all()}
    context.update(parent_context)  # Only necessary if you need any other context variables in `category_navbar.html`
    return context
```

Place this in a file named e.g. `nav_tags.py` in the `templatetags` directory of one of your apps. Then in your base template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
{% load nav_tags %}
...
<!-- Category Navbar -->
{% category_navbar %}
<!-- Category Navbar -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use context processor:
In settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'myproject.context_processors.get_categories',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Create a file called `context_processors.py` (in `myproject` directory in this case)

```
def get_categories(request):
    return {'categories': Category.objects.all()}
```

Now you can access to `categories` in all templates.
`{% for cat in categories %} ...`